# jhipster oauth : how can login via ajax from a different domain

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, csrf, jhipster

I'm trying to authenticate via `ajax` from a different domain of my `jhipster` instance but I get this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.xxx.it:9090/xxx-server-2.0.0/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://beta.xxx.it' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here you can find an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rpdyr97j/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to add a CORS filter of some kind to allow requests from other domains. See this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_filter_requests_for_cors